# AutoLayout UITableViewCell height multiple of TableView/Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uikit

I have a tableViewCell which contains an imageSlider that should be 40% of the screen height.

is that anyhow possible with autolayout? After adding the cell to to the tableView the height has already been calculated for the cell so any constraint added is ignored for the cell height.

i could implement heightForRow and return the correct value, but i was wondering if I could achieve this with AutoLayout alone?

```
cell.imageSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a height constraint to image slider and declare a respective iboutlet in cell. set its constant value to view.bounds.size.height/60.0. let me know if it works.

Comment: that is not what i'm looking for as i would have to update the constant manually every time the bounds change...

Comment: since the slider is inside the cell so it will not resize itself based on views bound automatically. you can place that code either in cellForRowAtIndexPath or in awakfromNib method in cell class.

Comment: your code (view.bounds.size.height / 60) does not work as it makes the slide a 60th of the view size. bounds.height * 0.4 would work but does not update automatically on rotation changes. So tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat seems to be the better place for this.

Comment: override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)

inside this method call tableview.reloadData

Comment: yes, it was my mistake. its should be view.bounds.size.height*0.4

Comment: well then tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat is the better place at it will be called automatically on size changes and I have to define it only once. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If that works for you then great. i just prefer not to do any configuration of cell in cellHeight method, as in that method we need to access cell for that indexPath explicitly that may not give exact cell always.

Comment: well for my case i only need to
if indexPath.row == 0 { return frame.height * 0.4 }. pretty simple. wish there would be an autolayout-only solution still...

Answer (score 0):

Add a height constraint to image slider and declare a respective iboutlet in cell. set its constant value to view.bounds.size.height*0.4.Set the top & bottom constraint of imageSlider from the superView(TableViewCell in your case).let me know if it works.
Also, add following code

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [self.imageSlider layoutIfNeeded];
    //OR 
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

layoutIfNeeded will automatically update the constraints.

Comment: that's about the same suggestion as @Deepak Kumar s one (see below). The height would not adapt to changing view.bounds.